# not sure if this is possible but how would I select the specific cell that was selected

Tags: ios

I think this must be possible but I'm wondering if there is any way I can get back the selected cell. I should mention that we are randomizing certain elements in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` so I am trying to get what the random data is. Since I get back the index path like this:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    NSLog(@"here is int: %i", path.row);
```

How would I go back and get the specific cell? I was thinking `cellForRowAtIndexPath` but would this give me back a new cell - I want to query the selected cell for content (like what content is in a label or which image is in an `ImageView`).

Comment: You don't go back to the cell to query its content. You use the index path to query the data source.

Comment: so we're randomizing some things so we actually do need that specific cell.

Comment: No, you should NEVER need to ask the cell for its data. It shouldn't actually have any data in it. You should randomise your data source into a random order so that it can be displayed to screen in that predefined random order. Then you just need the index path of the data source to get the data. If you want to change the order, re-randomise the data source and reload the collection/table view.

Comment: Yep, @Fogmeister is right, this violates the MVC principles. [See here.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Model-View-Controller/Model-View-Controller.html)

Comment: while I agree in a production app, this is just a demo app of a UI

Comment: No, production app, demo, anything, what you're doing is wrong and will make it harder in the future. It is always best to do the right thing.

Comment: Don't worry about it. the future of this app is like 24 hrs. It's sunday btw.

Comment: Doesn't matter what day it is. Sloppy code is still sloppy code :)

Comment: I guess the notion of context is lost on you; kinda sad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get it like this:

```
UITableViewCell* cell = (UITableViewCell*)sender;
```